# How to manage transactions using Hyperledger Composer API

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working in a POC using Hyperledger Composer v0.16.0 and Node.js SDK. I need to create a participant, then issue a new identity for that participant and finally create a business card and import it to my Business Network.

```
let createParticipantTrader = ((params) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let businessNetworkDefinition = await businessNetworkConnection.connect('admin@tutorial-network');
            let factory = businessNetworkDefinition.getFactory();
            let participantRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.biznet.Trader');
            await _createTrader(participantRegistry, factory, params);
            let newIdentity = await identity.issueNewIdentity(businessNetworkConnection, params);
            let newBusinessCard = await businessCard.createBusinessCard(newIdentity);
            await businessCard.importBusinessCard(newBusinessCard, params);
            let credentials = await _doPing(params);
            resolve(credentials);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I consider that code must run inside a transaction since if one of these operations fails a rollback is not done. I have been looking for a way of doing that, but all examples I found refer to Node.js ORM for differente databases.

Is there any option to manage these operations using Node.js SDK?

Answer (score 1):

So the TP functions example below uses Promises (near end of page) -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html

Async / await is based on the premise that the result of an `async` function is always a Promise. That Promise is created when starting the execution of the async function. The body is executed. Execution may finish permanently via return or throw.

see example here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/digitalproperty-network/lib/DigitalLandTitle.js